# The 'msolap' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, iis-7, ssas, olap

tried looking at other examples on this and am a bit confused.  I have 2 web servers that are load balanced and a sql server box (sql 2012). my cube is created on the sql server box (i see it in management studio).  when i try to access via my asp.net page i receive the above error.

now, i see the msolap110.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\110 on the sql box.  do i need to do something permission wise with the dll or something?  do i need to install analysis services on the web server?  is there a specific port or something (doubtful as sql is running fine).

connection string is as follows:
"Provider=msolap;Data Source=;Initial Catalog=AutoOLAPAW;Cube Name=SampleCube;"

going to try to force to use MSOLAP.5 but waiting on a republish from our security/deployment group.

this all works fine in dev but my (more secured/stripped down) prod/qa is where i'm seeing the issue. using iis7 on both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ADOMD.NET then either set CopyLocal=True on that reference on your ASP.NET source code so Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient is deployed with the web app... Or install SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi from:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49999

If you are using OLEDB then install SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi from that same link.

If you don’t want the SQL2012 version but want the latest then install from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-data-providers#download-the-latest-client-libraries-windows-installer) and use Provider=MSOLAP in the connection string (instead of a number like MSOLAP.5).

Comment: install that on the web server?

Comment: @user1272386 yes. Installs should be done on the server (unless you do the Copy Local) approach which will get the DLL onto the server

Comment: @user1272386 great. Happy to help. Could you click the checkmark to mark the answer?